# Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, node-oracledb

In my **Node.JS** project I use "[node-oracledb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0BcZ.png)" package which connect to remote **ORACLE** database. I developed that project in Windows 10 OS and it works fine. Now in production server (CentOS) I created Docker Image by next Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY / ./
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

It create Docker Image without any error. Then I create Docker Container but unfortunatly in logs I notice this error:

```
/src/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:68
      throw new Error(nodbUtil.getErrorMessage('NJS-045', nodeInfo));
      ^

Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 8.12.0 (linux, x64)
Cannot load /src/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
/src/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node: invalid ELF header
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:68:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

How to fix this problem?

I use instruction from [official documentation][2] to install client and set environment variable. The error is steal the same. Also I thought that I can try to install oracle client inside docker but I don't know how to make it. What do you think about that?

---

I change Dockerfile. I add this command:

```
RUM npm rebuild oracledb
```

It raise new close error:

```
/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:65
      throw new Error(nodbUtil.getErrorMessage('NJS-045', nodeInfo));
      ^

Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 11.4.0 (linux, x64)
Node.js require() error was:
  DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
Node.js require() mapped to /node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:65:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! saturn-backend@0.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the saturn-backend@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T12_06_50_714Z-debug.log
```

[image]

```
  [1]: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb
  [2]: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
```

Comment: I think your question is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951075/node-oracledb-invalid-elf-header-on-linux

Comment: @PedroSilva Can you check my post again. I add new information. It seems like I need to add `Oracle Instant Client` to `Docker`. Do you have any ideas how to make it?

Comment: Actually I think I can, give me 5 minutes because i had a project that uses this module with docker

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/18.3.0/Dockerfile I found this, check if it works.

Comment: In my project I have this https://pastebin.com/cYthsesZ those args are filled in jenkins howerver currently i don't have access to it to discover their values

Comment: @PedroSilva I also found that project before. Unfortunalty this line: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/15f8c73270d5252b306e7ded3380c1b9765ac446/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/18.3.0/Dockerfile#L19 failed.

Comment: @PedroSilva you last link is not available for me =(

Comment: @PedroSilva I add picture with error information. Can you check it?

Comment: It's working for me the linl, about the docker, i found this link too I'm not an expert on this so my knowledge is basic, another option is to download the instant client for linux add to your project. check this https://technology.amis.nl/2016/04/06/create-oracledb-enabled-node-js-application-container/